# Doubly Linked List Bubblesort, Reverse method now broken

Tags: c++, sorting, doubly-linked-list

So I've recently updated my Bubblesort (sorts alphabetically) to work with a linked list.

Although now my previously working reverse method breaks the list. (Previously worked if I didn't do the single list bubble sort first)

Bubble sort and Swap.

```
void bubbleSort() {
    City *temp = NULL;
    City *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) { //for the rest in list
        if (current->getName().compare(current->next->getName()) > 0) { //compare distance
            if (current == head) {
                head = current->next;
            }
            swap(current, current->next);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Swap

```
void swap(City* i, City* j) {
    if (i->previous)  i->previous->next = j;
    if (j->previous)  j->previous->next = i;
    if (i->next) i->next->previous = j;
    if (j->next) j->next->previous = i;
    City* temp;
    temp = i->previous;
    i->previous = j->previous;
    j->previous = temp;
    temp = i->next;
    i->next = j->next;
    j->next = temp;
}
```

This is the now broken reverse list.

```
void reverseList() {
    City *temp = NULL;
    City *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        temp = current->previous;
        current->previous = current->next;
        current->next = temp;
        current = current->previous;

    }
    if (temp != NULL) {
        head = temp->previous;
    }
}
```

**Question** What have I missed out of my bubble sort that breaks the list?

Comment: Why not just swap the data and leave the pointers alone?

Comment: Because City has alot of data, looking back if I had wrapped them in a NODE it would have worked although that is not a option unless I cannot get this to work at all.

Comment: What is "a lot of data"?  All you have to do is rewrite `swap` to swap the data, and to do that you take advantage of `std::swap` instead writing all of that code with `temp` variables.  Also, bubble sort is an `O(n^2)` loop, but I see only one while loop.  It should be two loops, one nested in the other.

Comment: Hmm okay I guess I can I'll look into it and report back thanks!

Comment: You should also take a look at your bubble sort.  Bubble sort should be written to take multiple passess through the data to sort, but your loop only does one pass.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Ah found the error through debugging.current != NULL should be current-> != NULL. @PaulMcKenzie I also had to add the multiple passes so if you would like to put that as the answer I would accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is your bubble sort implementation.  It should be making multiple passes through the data, since bubble sort has `O(n*n)` complexity, where `n` is the number of items to be sorted.

In other words, you need to execute the `while` loop in `bubbleSort` until you've detected that the data is sorted.  That can be done either by using a boolean flag that is only set when a `swap` occurs and then testing that flag, or just make `n` passes through the data.